# Ruby: Reading Arrays of Hashes from YAML

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, yaml

I have two dads going into my YAML file, but only one family comes out. What happened to Sam? How do I get both out?

```
## dads.rb
require 'yaml'
require 'pp'

dad=[]

dad[0] = {:name => "Joe", :kids => ["Mary", "John"]}
dad[1] = {:name => "Sam", :kids => ["Sam Jr", "Samantha", "Samizdat"]}

open('dads.yml' , 'w') do |f|
    dad.each do |d|
        f.write YAML::dump(d)
    end
end

family = []
open('dads.yml') do |f|
    family << YAML::load(f.read)
end

pp fams
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You dump multiple YAML documents but only read back one. Instead, you can just dump and read the whole array:

```
require 'yaml'

dads = []
dads << {:name => "Joe", :kids => ["Mary", "John"]}
dads << {:name => "Sam", :kids => ["Sam Jr", "Samantha", "Samizdat"]}

open('dads.yml', 'w') { |f| YAML::dump(dads, f) }

family = YAML::load(File.read('dads.yml'))

p family
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code currently creates separate "documents" within the YAML output. By default, `YAML::load` will just read in the first document. Niklas' answer is definitely the way you should go, but if you absolutely had to deal with multiple documents, you could use the `load_documents` method:

```
family = YAML.load_documents(File.read("dads.yml"))
# => [{:name=>"Joe", :kids=>["Mary", "John"]}, {:name=>"Sam", :kids=>["Sam Jr", "Samantha", "Samizdat"]}]
```

Comment: Good to know :) I just tried to get `each_document` to work, but that doesn't seem to be available in the new YAML implementation.. The documentation is not the best I've seen.

Comment: Even in the old engine (syck), `each_document` was deprecated and just called `load_documents` anyway. Psych only handles `load_documents`.

Comment: ah. i see that i was creating multiple documents. the .each operator didn't help. now it's done. thanks.